# How could I post an answer to a on hold question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I have found this question ([How would even more internet regulation hinder terrorism?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/161276/70738)). I first wonder whether it was on topic here, saw that it has been migrated and decided to write an answer (if it has been migrated from politics, it should not be on topic there...).

I spend some time writing it, posted, and was surprised to see that my post was accepted while it had been already put on hold...

So I want to know whether I should delete it because the question was already on hold, and I would really be glad to understand how it could have been accepted...

Comment: if you started writing it before it was put on hold, it would be accepted as an answer

Comment: @schroeder I was surprised, because on SO, I could not post the answer if the question had been put on hold in the meanwhile. Are the rules different here? Or is it related to the double migration attempt?

Comment: Also see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252711/this-answer-was-posted-after-the-question-was-closed-how-is-that-possible

Comment: @Arminius: thanks for the information! The meta post fully answers my question.